# jQuery Mobile Hyperlinks Not Working in iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, uiwebview

I have a jQuery Page that I'm loading up in a web view in my iOS app.

The hyperlinks however are not working - on tapping the button, nothing happens. And if i remove the `rel="external"`, i get Error Loading Page.

I've tested on browsers and its fine. Any ideas what I'm missing?

```
<a id="topSmallHeader" rel="external" href="home.html" data-role="button" data-shadow="false">Home</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: define "not working". `rel="external"` loads `home.html` via HTTP not Ajax.

Comment: On tapping the link nothing happens. And if i remove rel="external" i get Error loading page

Comment: Is it the same problem like this https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/597

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link above in the comment this may a solution,

```
 <a id="topSmallHeader" rel="external" href="home.html" data-role="button" data-shadow="false" onclick="window.location = $(this).attr('href')">Home</a>
```